# Show/miniseries which aired on HBO in the early '90s, featuring "Water Police"

Tags: story-identification, tv, dystopia, miniseries

This is something I've been totally unable to find any information about through search engines. In the early/mid '90s, I remember seeing what I think was a show or miniseries about a dystopian future where water was in extremely short supply, and used as a means of control over the populace. The regime's thuggish police force was known as the "Water Police" (and I distinctly remember a "WP" logo).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If "WP" stands for "Water & Power" instead of "Water Police" then you might have been watching [*Tank Girl*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/) (1995).

[image: Water & Power logo]

It's set in a world where rain has basically stopped falling, and everywhere is desert.  The titular hero is fighting against the evil Water & Power who are trying to monopolize the remaining water supplies.

Comment: Took a glance at the trailer and this definitely might have been it! I'll have to check it out, thanks.

Comment: I thought the same when I first read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this Aussie show. Not Police though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrol_Boat_(TV_series)

Comment: Does this series involve a water shortage? If not, it doesn't match on a key point of the description. Also note that the OP has already marked [DavidW's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264806/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) -- as denoted by the green tick next to that answer -- which means the OP believes that answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe The Wire? Baltimore Police Department did have some boat action.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct show, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. Do note, however, that the OP has already marked [DavidW's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264806/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) -- as denoted by the green tick next to that answer -- which means the OP believes that answer is correct.

Comment: 2002 is too late to have been early/mid-90's.  There was apparently a 1997 show by that name, but it's not very well known (almost no info on IMDB) and as far as I can tell doesn't take place in Baltimore, so it's probably not the one you're thinking of.

Comment: The Wire was about a dystopian present, not a dystopian future.